# Where does the rect come from in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UICollectionView` for which I've implemented a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implemented the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method. My view is scrollable and I've implemented the `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` method to return YES. So every time I scroll, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` gets called.

But when I'm scrolling around in the top half of my view, the rect it gets called with is the rect for the whole collection (e.g. `{{0, 0}, {320, 1136}} {{0, 567}, {320, 548}}`), and when I scroll past halfway the rect becomes only the bottom half (i.e. `{{0, 568}, {320, 568}} {{0, 568}, {320, 548}}`). This completely breaks my layout. I need layoutAttributesForElementsInRect to always get called with the rect for the whole view.

Why did it use that other rect, and how can I turn off the rect-changing behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ho, my collection view had two elements and when I was rendering both it would lay out the rectangle for both of them but when I was rendering one it would lay out the rectangle for one of them. I can fix it by counting up the number of elements and multiplying by the dimensions of each one to get the right rect.